# setInterval works one step later in android

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I use the setInterval function with react native,
It works a bit late on android.
I do not know why.
On iOS, it works fine.
I want to make android work the same as iOS.
Help...

```html
<Button title="exec" onPress={() => {
  this.abc = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('going...');
  }, 100);
}} />
<Button title="stop" onPress={() => clearInterval(this.abc)} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems too late, but I found a solution.
That is the use of 'requestAnimationFrame'.
This is a much more sophisticated and recommended method than setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue, I guess the problem is on android setIterval waits for time and then perform action, but on ios function is called first and then the next time start, what I did on android is befor setinterval called that function, once

```
<Button title="exec" onPress={() => {
console.log('going...');
  this.abc = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('going...');
  }, 100);
}} />
<Button title="stop" onPress={() => clearInterval(this.abc)} />
```

Comment: It seems too late, but I found a solution.
That is the use of 'requestAnimationFrame'.
This is a much more sophisticated and recommended method than setInterval.